# 228A codeforces getting wrong answer code 19

Tags: c++

this is a problem on code forces:

> Valera the Horse is going to the party with friends. He has been
> following the fashion trends for a while, and he knows that it is very
> popular to wear all horseshoes of different color. Valera has got four
> horseshoes left from the last year, but maybe some of them have the
> same color. In this case he needs to go to the store and buy some few
> more horseshoes, not to lose face in front of his stylish comrades.
>
> Fortunately, the store sells horseshoes of all colors under the sun
> and Valera has enough money to buy any four of them. However, in order
> to save the money, he would like to spend as little money as possible,
> so you need to help Valera and determine what is the minimum number of
> horseshoes he needs to buy to wear four horseshoes of different colors
> to a party. Input
>
> The first line contains four space-separated integers s1, s2, s3, s4
> (1 ≤ s1, s2, s3, s4 ≤ 109) — the colors of horseshoes Valera has.
>
> Consider all possible colors indexed with integers. Output
>
> Print a single integer — the minimum number of horseshoes Valera needs
> to buy.

**Examples**

```
Input 1 7 3 3 
Output 1
Input 7 7 7 7
Output 3
```

my solution's output is right, but has  ***Wrong answer on test 19*** .
**my solution is:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //input
    int input[4];
    int i, j, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
      
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < 4; j++) {
           if (count == 3)break;
            if (input[i] == input[j]) {
                count += 1;
            }
       }
    }
    cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

The testcase 19 is:

```
Input
147784432 947653080 947653080 947653080
Participant's output
3
Jury's answer
2
Checker comment
wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '2', found: '3'
```

Comment: Could you please show the error that you got. This runs and compiles fine for me

Comment: not knowing a thing about codeforce I bet this is time limit exceeded or something of this kind because of O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: @zubergu Not really, the code has O(1) complexity, because input size is fixed. OP gets "Wrong answer on test 19"

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Indeed what does that mean? Is this test 19 you wrote down Tamara?

Comment: @tamara You could optimize a little by moving the `if(count ==3) break;` to just below `count += 1`. As this is the only place you can really judge that only once per iteration. O and that will only break the inner loop not the outer.

Comment: @tamara I have suggested an edit for the qsn to include the testcase 19. In short, your code fails in these types of inputs `a b b b`. here when i = 1, check += 2 and when i = 2, check += 1 making check = 3. here you are counting the last b twice. you can avoid this by skipping equal elements.

Comment: I guess an easier strategy is to count the number of different elements, and to output `4 - count`.

Comment: Using the standard library: `sort(begin(input), end(input)); cout << 4 - distance(begin(input), unique(begin(input), end(input)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a slight modification to your code to count the number of distinct numbers and output `4 - count`.

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //input
    int input[4];
    int i, j, count = 1;
 
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
      
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(input[i] == input[j]) break;
       }
       if(i == j) count++;
    }
    cout << (4-count);
    return 0;
}
```

Accepted in codeforces.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly optimized version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //input
    int input[4];
    int i, j, count = 0;
    bool done = false;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
      
    }
    for (i = 0; (i < 3) && (!done); i++) {
        for (j = i+1; (j < 4) && (!done); j++) {
            if (input[i] == input[j]) {
                count += 1;
                done = count == 3;
            }
       }
    }
    cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the same issue @Bart

Comment: Just realized you can have loop i below 3. But please look into susanth29 his comment.